# 5GHZ wifi is not showing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, broadcom

I am trying to find my 5Ghz ssid and then I will try to connect it but it's not showing up.

My `lspci |grep -i net` output is

`bash03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)`

`sudo iwlist wlo1 freq` output is

```
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Channel 157 : 5.785 GHz
          Channel 161 : 5.805 GHz
          Channel 165 : 5.825 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
```

Kindly help to overcome the issue.

Comment: Do you see any 5GHz access points?  If not, your card is only 2GHz -- do not be misled by the 802.11n designation, that does not imply 5Ghz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The  Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n wifi card is *not* a Dual-Band card.  That is, it only operates on the 2.4GHz band of wifi network technologies, even though the system says it can support 5Ghz frequencies.

If you have *confirmed* 5GHz networks are in your area, but still cant' see the networks, then the card is not able to support 5Ghz and the card is falsely reporting 5GHz support.

You would need a Dual Band wifi card in your computer to be able to use 5Ghz connections.  (The 'n' designation of wifi standard on the card doesn't indicate that you have 5GHz capabilities)

Comment: Is there any way to be sure?

Comment: @sam I already looked up the specific card you indicated.  HP models had this card in them, and their own forum indicates it's a single-band card (see https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Broadcom-BCM43142-802-11-bgn-Wi-Fi-M-2-Adapter-to-5Ghz/td-p/6085221 where they say  "That is a hardware issue.  You can't turn a 2.4 GHz card into a 5.0 GHz card with a driver update." which indicates the card is a 2.4GHz only card)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was being mislead by the command output.